# Netbeans output issue

Tags: java, netbeans

I have an issue with Netbeans.

When I execute my java code, I have the message Build Successful but no output is produced anymore even when I am building a new class with simple message like "Hello World".

Have you ever experienced such issue, do you know where this problem can come from and how to solve it?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: right click on class file and choose run.

Comment: I don't know why it doesn't work with F6 but with right click it's working. 

Thank you very much!

Comment: @AliDindar - if you are happy with the answer. please accept.

Comment: I'm new sry how can I accept it?

Answer (score -1):

When you create two classes with main methods like below which one should run?

```
class A {
  public static void main(String args[]){}
}

class B {
  public static void main(String args[]){}
}
```

**The one which you set as default class first (in netbeans).**

To view default class set in netbeans: Right-click the project in the Projects window and choose **Properties** then find **Run** tab.

Here you can setup your main class.